# browser.params from config shows "undefined"

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

Any idea why console.log in the last line below shows "undefined"?  browser should also be available when calling browser.params.

```
exports.config = {
    params: {
        login: {
            user: 'xyz@elementum.com',
            password: 'xyz',
            fullName: 'xyz'
        }
    }
    onPrepare: function() {
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
    }
```

---

```
describe('When loggin in, ', function() {

    var login = new LoginPage();
        describe("clicking on the login button ", function() {
            it('should be able to log user in.', function() {
            login.get(); //browser.get('/#/login');

            //The log below shows "1. browser.params.login.username =undefined"
            console.log("1. browser.params.login.password =" + browser.params.login.password);

        });
```

Comment: Are you sure you are actually using this config to run the tests? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe  yes, I am sure.  Somehow, browser.params.login.password works  if I print out the correct value in a page object.  From within a jasmine 'it' test,  browser.params.login.password does NOT show the correct value.

Comment: Try to convert it into json object and try accessing the values as mentioned below.

Comment: JSON.parse (browser.params.login).password